# How to stop android textview auto scrolling when inside-link clicked

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview looks like this:

```
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brief_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/brief_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        />
```

And below it,there is a 'more' button, which has a function to set the textview's max lines from 4-10, for switching textview to part or full content.

Here the problem, when max line is 4, once a inside-link clicked, all of text scrolled up a little bit ,and it makes some words from the fifth lines could be seen. How can I stop this auto scrolling? Thx!

P.S. I really need those auto-Links. But I wish the textview do not scroll automatically when links clicked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer after searching google:

[Movements are added here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#4007)

And what does the [LinkMovementMethod](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.java#LinkMovementMethod) do is shown here.

Thus, all I need is removing the MovementMethod where the text view is scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the TextView of scrolling in this case, you should set the following xml attribute to your TextView:

```
singleLine=true
```

This shall remain the text content in the TextView stable and static, and when you click on your links the text will not scroll up.

Comment: That worked for me, please mark it as the right answer